# Confusion about the summation convention

Tags: conventions, notation

In Liouville's system, the kinetic energy has the following form,

$$T = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}f_{i}(q_{i})\dot{q}_{i}^{2}$$
As one can see, that index $i$ has appeared three times and repeated indices are summed over, therefore will it be valid to write $T$ as?

$$T = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}f_{i}(q_{i})\sum_{i}\dot{q}_{i}^{2}$$
Such that $\sum_{i}f_{i}(q_{i})>0$.

Hopefully, someone can make any comment about this.

Comment: How many examples have you checked to see whether the two values of $T$ are equal?

Comment: It is in Goldstein problem 2.17

Comment: We don't normally mix Sigma notation and the Einstein summation convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What’s wrong with
$$
f_1(q_1)\dot{q}_1^2+ f_2(q_2)\dot{q}_2^2+\ldots
$$
*i.e.* one function $f$ for each coordinate?

Admittedly this is uncommon but imagine for instance you have translational and rotational motion.  Then $q_1=s$ (say distance on an incline) $f_1=\frac{m}{2}$ and $f_2={\cal I}$ where ${\cal I}$ is the moment of inertia, with $q_2=\theta$ the distance rolled on the incline.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal multiplies two sums, which should use different dummy indices, but the original expression actually needs $f_i\dot{q}_i^2$ to only introduce one dummy-index degree of freedom.

To write $T$ in the summation convention, you can introduce a diagonal matrix $f_{ij}$ with eigenvalues $f_i$, then write $T=\tfrac12\dot{q}_if_{ij}\dot{q}_j$.

Comment: Or just throw in a Kronecker delta $\delta_{i,j}$

Comment: @Mauricio If all the $f_i$ are the same, $f_{ij}\propto\delta_{ij}$. I don't think you can make it work more generally, if only because of how the entries of $f_{ij}$ change under an arbitrary rotation.

Comment: Oh my bad, I think you are right.